# How to sort the OrderItems in the cart by its category on Broadleaf Commerce?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Broadleaf Commerce site

I need to sort the OrderItems in the cart by its product category. Currently, I am using the comparator to sort the OrderItems.

What is the best or right way to customize the default sort for Cart OrderItems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are currently doing something like this:

```
List<OrderItem> items = cart.getOrderItems();
Collections.sort(items, comparator);
```

and I also assume that by "default sort" you mean that you want to change the behavior when you call `cart.getOrderItems()`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the behavior of the query that occurs when you call `getOrderItems()` as this is a JPA-generated query on the `OrderItem` collection within `OrderImpl`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", targetEntity = OrderItemImpl.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region="blOrderElements")
@AdminPresentationCollection(friendlyName="OrderImpl_Order_Items",
        tab = TabName.General)
protected List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

Because of this you really only have 3 options:

1. Override the `OrderImpl` class and change the implementation of the `getOrderItems()` method. Unless you really *needed* to extend this (like to add another column to `BLC_ORDER`) then this isn't a great solution since it will add another table to the database that isn't actually used. See the [Broadleaf extending entities tutorial](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/data-and-service-models/extending-entities). You can also technically avoid the multi-table inheritance by switching to single-table inheritance which is detailed at the bottom of that doc
2. Add your own query somewhere in a service method that manually queries for `OrderItem` for the order with a JPA query
3. Do what you are currently doing and sort the order items manually after retrieval with your comparator. You might consider adding a Thymeleaf utility method to have it available to you in your templates

Comment: I will go for the 3rd option, thanks for your prompt reply.